# service/agent to capture activity on windows file system

Tags: c++, windows, logging, syslog

Is it possible to develop a service/agent to capture activity on the file system as they happen without actually turning on windows auditing?

Not sure if windows have a product limitation to achieve this result. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows and Linux both offer operating system APIs to allow this. The API is most often exposed in C but has been wrapped for use in many languages.

For example in Windows you can start by reading the documentation for the `FindFirstChangeNotification(...)`.

Some APIs can work on network-attached and temporarily attached storage. Sometimes the storage driver must implement certain features to enable efficient change notifications; not all bother to do this.

Windows and Linux have different APIs, and there is no Posix standard for this feature that would work across both. However, popular languages like Python or Ruby may have extensions, libraries, or modules that hide the OS differences for you and present a standard API to their particular users.

Finally, you could brute force a comparison between snapshots. While this might be inefficient and, depending on the implementation, might miss specific changes, it would probably work on any storage medium or architecture.